# GPU video output is not working and I don't have onboard graphics

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

I just built a system with a [x8dah+](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DAH_-F.cfm) mobo that was refurbished and has two xeons on it. I installed a gtx 1060 from evga bstock on it and am using a 750w psu to power the system. The issue when I turn on my machine, everything seems fine, but when I try to hook it up to the monitor, the monitor picks up nothing from the graphics card (connected through hdmi). The graphics card glows white when the machine is on, but only one fan spins. I tried moving the graphics card to a different pci-e slot and using different hdmi cables, but the issue persists. I have does not have onboard graphics either, so I kind of need the graphics card to work. Also the motherboard. Is the issue that the motherboard only has pci-e 2.0, or is the issue not with compatibility, but with the hardware?

Comment: GTX1060 requires PCIe 3.0.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia no it does not. You can use it on a 2.0 slot.

Comment: @DrZoo The Nvidia specs say PCIe 3.0. That and *only one fan spins* pretty much explains why *GPU video output is not working*. And why would Nvidia not explicitly say it's backwards compatible with 2.0 if it is?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia What about the Nvidia page? PCIe 3.0 is backwards compatible with PCIe 2.0. It does not require a PCIe 3.0 slot.

Comment: @DrZoo The backwards compatibility as I understand it is like PCI3 2.0 devices can work in a PCIe 3.0, not necessarily the other way around. Do you have experience with or a reliable source confirming your assertion? And what about the OP's problem, any idea?

Comment: Which PCIe slot are you putting the card in? An x4, an x8 or x16 slot?

Comment: @DrZoo A GTX1060 requires a x16 slot. Or do you think it can also fit the smaller ones somehow? Again, quotation please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85018/discussion-between-drzoo-and-gabrielagarcia).

Comment: More information: Both fans seem to stop spinning, I think its b/c the gpu is just no being used by the motherboard so if turning off both fans

Comment: Looking at your board, it has a VGA ouput on the board. What Xeon's do you have?

Comment: @DrZoo No, my model of the motherboard does not have vga. I checked the manual and there are three versions, I have the one w/o on board graphics. Also I have x5680s on it

Comment: Do you have a different computer you can try the gpu in, or a different gpu? If you’ve tried putting the gpu into multiple  x16 slots, ensured all of the cables are tight, and have your monitor on the right output..I’m not sure what to suggest, other then RMA the card and try a new one.